# Python installation directory

Tags: python, directory

On command $which python3$ , the location says /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 on my Mac. Is this okay for python to be in other directory than /usr/local/ ?

Comment: If you followed the installation instructions, then it was installed in a place that makes sense and shouldn't cause a problem. If you are observing something going wrong, then ask about it. Otherwise, you don't have a programming question, you have a "how do I use my computer?" question.

Comment: Does it work? Then the answer is: yes.

Comment: Yes. It will work. I mean if you change the location of installation directory, mac os will recognize it and `python3` instruction will work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It will work. I mean if you change the location of installation directory, mac os will recognize it and python3 instruction will work.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's absolutely ok. But it's better to create a project wise virtual env so that you don't messed up installing so many third party libraries globally in your system which could break system tools and other projects.
Installing vitualenv:

```
python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv
```

Creating a virtual environment.

```
cd {{your project directory}}
python3 -m venv env
```

Activate the virtualenv:

```
source env/bin/activate
```

Now if you run `which python` you will see the python is from your newly created virtual env.